# Time allocation for training a Mask R-CNN based on a pretrained model

Tags: tensorflow, mask

I'm training a Mask R-CNN model using coco pre-trained weights in a Google Cloud deep learning virtual machine with 32vCPUs and 120GB RAM, it's been running over 20h and it's still in epoch 1/30. The script is being run in the background using and the output is saved in a .log file, that hasn't been updated since 15 hours ago. My dataset contains 2050 images. How can I make sure that my model is still running? How long does Mask R-CNN take generally to be trained?

Answer (score 0):

How many steps are in every epoch? How many images are in your validation set? If you are using https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN as network, it will test the network with the validation set at the end of an epoch, and that may take a long time, specially if you are not using a GPU.